# Start/Stop SharePoint Server on demand

Tags: 2013

I'm running SharePoint Server 2013 on my work machine (4Gb RAM) but I'm usually not using/developing SharePoint, so I'm looking the solution to start/stop whole SharePoint Server on demand. For example, if I'm switch developing from ASP.NET application to SharePoint - I want to run script (or something else) that start SharePoint Server, but when I switching from SharePoint to ASP.NET I want to stop SharePoint Server - because I need resources to develop another application.
Upgrading is not possible, due to hardware restriction (I've old laptop).

Is it possible, if yes, can you share solution?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using virtual development machines? With hyper-v, virtual box or similar?

Comment: @RobertLindgren I've thought about it, but it will generally slow my machine

Comment: Your machine will not work very well with 2013 in 4gb ram however you do I'm afraid :(

Comment: @RobertLindgren I'm also thought so, but after some perfomance tuning it's runs with 3-3.5Gb :)

Answer (score 3):

4GB isn't really enough RAM for a SharePoint 2013 server (even for development).  However, if you want to script turning on and off SharePoint services, you can put the following in a .CMD file:

```
net stop SPTimerV4
net stop SPAdminV4
net stop MSSQLSERVER 
(this one is to stop SQL, you may need to replace it with the service name for SQL, you can get this in the Windows Services screen)
iisreset -stop
```

Then to start the services:

```
net start SPTimerV4
net start SPAdminV4
net start MSSQLSERVER
iisreset -start
```